# Notice: Undefined index PHP error

Tags: php, mysql, database

This line:

```
<?php echo $row_stuCompSci['Cid']; ?>
```

is giving me the undefined index error. But I don't understand why that is giving me an error when other queries don't. Here's the query I used. This is all made in Dreamweaver

```
mysql_select_db($database_project, $project);
$query_stuCompSci = "SELECT compsci.CSid FROM compsci WHERE NOT EXISTS  ( SELECT      studentcourses.Cid FROM studentcourses WHERE studentcourses.Cid=compsci.CSid )";
$stuCompSci = mysql_query($query_stuCompSci, $project) or die(mysql_error());
$row_stuCompSci = mysql_fetch_assoc($stuCompSci);
$totalRows_stuCompSci = mysql_num_rows($stuCompSci);
```

In the query, the table studentcourses has two columns (Sid, Cid) and the 2nd table compsci has two columns as well (CSid, Credits).

The query gets whatever Cid does not exist in student courses and when I test the query it works fine, however, when I try to see my website live it gives me the index error. If need be, I can copy my whole code in here but it about 220 lines long.

Comment: Please do not use [`mysql_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) functions; they are in the process of being deprecated. It is recommended to use [`mysqli_`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for all new code. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Your query contained:

```
SELECT compsci.CSid FROM ...
```

Note the query is `CSid`, not `Cid`

Comment: Wow thanks! That worked. Now how can I get the query so that it returns the table with only the studentcourses.Sid that I acquire from the URL/previous page? Sorry if that's a bit confusing. It's currently showing the results for the whole table which is not what I need.

Comment: You should open a new question for that. There's no space to address it here.

Answer (score 1):

it mean that you havent selected   `Cid`  in query try

```
 "SELECT compsci.Cid,compsci.CSid FROM compsci WHERE NOT EXISTS  ( SELECT      studentcourses.Cid FROM studentcourses WHERE studentcourses.Cid=compsci.CSid )";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Cid` in Php

```
<?php echo $row_stuCompSci['Cid']; ?>
```

but haven't selected `Cid` in query. Do this

```
SELECT compsci.Cid,compsci.CSid FROM ....
```